# Analysis of ng4 vs f4

Tags: online-chess

[image: Ng4+ vs f4]

Why is it that ng4 is the best move here? I played f4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a pretty forcing move, White does not have many options to react to it and all are painful.

The most obvious question, why cannot White take?

Because hxg4 Rh8+ is forced mate.

If Rook takes we just take Back, White has no meaningful checks and we are just up a rook.

Finally, if White dodges with Kh1 we take the knight, and White still cannot take ours due to Rh8+ being devastating.

```
[Variant "From Position"]
[FEN "r3r3/p1p3k1/1b6/5pN1/Q1Pp2n1/P2Pq2P/1P2P1RK/R7 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kh1 (1. hxg4 Rh8+ 2. Nh3 Rxh3#) (1. Rxg4 fxg4 2. Qd7+ Re7 3. Qxg4 Qxe2+ 4. Kg1 Qxg4+
5. hxg4)Qxg5 2. hxg4 Rh8+ 3. Kg1 Qe3+ 4. Rf2 Rh2
```